# TYPO3 - Using Site Configuration in TypoScript - BaseUrl

Tags: yaml, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

in the TYPO3 Docu we can read the example: [Using Site Configuration in TypoScript](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInTypoScript.html)

Site-Config Yaml to typoscript.
But this Code-Example work only in the "page" corner.

```
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.data = site:base
page.10.wrap = This is your base URL: |
```

And i use this here in the FLUIDTEMPLATE:

```
page {
  10 {
    variables {
      # BaseURL
      siteConfigBase = TEXT
      siteConfigBase {
        data = site:base
      }
   }
}
```

This works fine, in the f.debug is the right output `siteConfigBase = https://example.org`

How can i pass the values to `config.baseURL` ?

Answer (score 0):

`config.baseURL` supports only strings but not `stdWrap`.

But you can use a condition to get what you want:

```
[site("identifier") == "foo"]
config.baseURL = foo
[global]
```

The identifier is the name of the folder of your site configuration.

Comment: yes, only string :(  
the Problem is, we have 50 websites, with language and many developer url´s :(  
at the moment we have this: config.baseURL = /

Comment: Why exactly do you need the base href? Since the introduction of the site configuration I haven't used base href once.

Comment: we need this for the absolute-url, for the head base url...

Comment: Yeah, I know what it is used for. But why? If we use multiple domains with the same TYPO3 installation, we do the redirects in the .htaccess file to make sure there is no duplicate content due to multiple domains with the same content.

Comment: no, the Problem is not the duplicate content, the problem is, we need for all projects the right `<base href="https://example.org/">`

Comment: I still don't get it. Why is a full domain name in this case better than just `/`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this TypoScript. Which adds the base tag behind the head tag.

```
page.headTag = TEXT
page.headTag.data = site.base
page.headTag.wrap = <head><base href="|">
```